# try-catch statement interrupt try-block as soon as exception is thrown

Tags: javascript, exception, try-catch

**Research:**

According to [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) :

> The try...catch statement marks a block of statements to try, and
>   specifies a response, should an exception be thrown.

If I understand this correctly the entire try-block will be executed. This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26994308/java-try-catch-when-is-the-program-flow-interrupted) post confirmed myself.

**My Question:**

Is it possible to interrupt a try-block as soon as an exception is thrown to get into the catch-block?

Yes: How would this behavior be achieved?
No: Are there other ways to achieve this behavior?

Comment: `If I understand this correctly the entire try-block will be executed` no, I don't know where you got that idea from. If you have three lines of code in the `try` block and the first one throws an exception, then the other two would be skipped and the `catch` is executed.  The linked answer also claims that. If there is no exception, then the `catch` would not be executed.

Comment: If an exception is thrown, the lines that have not executed yet in the try will not run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
try {
  console.log('omg');
  throw new Error('omg');
  console.log('ahhhhhh!!!!!');
} catch {
  console.log('caught');
}
```

I think JS does what you want. The linked SO is for Java.

Comment: In fairness, it behaves the same way with any language that has `try...catch` which I've ever seen.

Comment: I figured but didn't know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The SO post you linked is about Java, not Javascript.
So the answers there might not be applicable.

As far as I know, the catch block will get triggered the moment an error is thrown.
And you can throw an error any time you want:

```js
try {
  console.log( 'before error: this should log' );
  throw new Error( 'Trigger catch!' );
  console.log( 'after error: this should not log' );
}
catch( error ) {
  console.log( `catch block got the error: ${ error.message }` );
}
```

Comment: `The SO post you linked is about Java, not Javascript. So the answers there might not be applicable.` they are, as the construct works the same way. The only significant difference is that in Java you can choose which exceptions to catch, e.g., only `NullPointerException` but not `InvalidArgumentException`. Which isn't important in this case. Besides, the accepted answer in the linked question already states `Instruction flow is interrupted when any exception occurs anywhere.`.

Comment: The try/catch block works the same way indeed, but there's still a difference in the error object interface. So if the OP did not notice the difference in language, they might try to use the methods `.getMessage()`, `.printStackTrace()`, and others mentioned in the Java answer. So I feel it is warranted to make this clear to the OP that not everything in those answers will work exactly the same in Javascript.